# Metal 2 vs OpenCL 1.2 for compute: what is Metal missing?

Tags: opencl, metal

I have an OpenCL 1.2 application that I would like to run on iOS.
So, my only choice for gpgpu is Metal. I am curious about what is missing
in Metal relative to OpenCL ?  My current app makes heavy use of OpenCL images,
and compute features such as `popcnt` .

Comment: I don't know OpenCL, but I doubt Metal is missing much, since it was designed much later. You can see from the [Metal Shader Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) (PDF) that it provides the `popcount()` function. Compute functions in Metal can read from and write to textures as well as buffers, if that's what OpenCL images are used for.

Comment: One thing that springs to mind is support for double-precision floating-point.

Comment: @KenThomases if one of the Ken Thomases converts that comment to an answer, I will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know OpenCL, but I doubt Metal is missing much, since it was designed much later. You can see from the [Metal Shader Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) (PDF) that it provides the `popcount()` function.

Compute functions in Metal can read from and write to textures as well as buffers, if that's what OpenCL images are used for.

As warrenm points out, Meta does not support double-precision floating-point types.